# Can't get ajax rowSelect event to fire on PrimeFace5.0 DataTable

Tags: ajax, primefaces, datatable, event-handling

I am using a PrimeFace5.0 DataTable. I want to add the ajax rowSelect event to it. However, when a row is clicked, the event is not fired. My table and Ajax are declared like so:

```
<p:dataTable id="leTable" 
    value="#{leList.leItems}" 
    var="leItem" 
    rowKey="#{leItem.id}" 
    scrollable="true" 
    scrollHeight="100%" 
    selection="#{leList.selectedLEs}" 
    selectionMode="multiple"
    rowIndexVar="rowIndex" 
    resizableColumns="true" 
    liveResize="true"
    >
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" 
    listener="#{leAction.onLeRowSelect}" 
    update=":form:rowIndexId"
    onstart="getLeRowIndexId(event)">
    </p:ajax>
....
</p:dataTable>
```

Action-Bean:
    public void onLeRowSelect(SelectEvent event)
    {
    ....
    }

The whole thing worked well with the **Prime Faces 4.0**. But after switching to **version 5.0 it no longer works**. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Your code works for me. Maybe you forgot form tag. Specify more code.